# "permanent" GKE kubectl service account authentication

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine

I deploy apps to *Kubernetes* running on *Google Cloud* from CI. CI makes use of *kubectl* config which contains auth information (either in directly CVS or templated from the env vars during build)

CI has seperate *Google Cloud* service account and I generate *kubectl* config via

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key-file.json`

and

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name>`

This sets the *kubectl* config but the token expires in few hours.

What are my options of having 'permanent' *kubectl* config other than providing CI with key file during the build and running `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those asking the same question and upvoting.

This is my current sollution:

For some time I treated `key-file.json` as an identity token, put it to the CI config and used it within container with `gcloud` CLI installed. I used the key file/token to log in to GCP and let `gcloud` [generate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) `kubectl` config - the same approach used for GCP container registry login.

This works fine but using `kubectl` in CI is kind of antipattern. I switched to deploying based on container registry push events. This is relatively easy to do in k8s with [keel](https://github.com/keel-hq/keel) [flux](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux), etc. So CI has only to push Docker image to the repo and its job ends there. The rest is taken care of within k8s itself so there is no need for `kubectl` and it's config in the CI jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [RBAC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) (role based access control) which will authenticate the role avoiding expiration in contrast to certificates which currently expires as mentioned.